# Stripe Connect Customer Data in Staging

Tags: production-environment, staging, stripe-connect

I want to use a clone of my production database, and be able to load users with `stripe_customer_id`created using **Live API Key** in a staging environment, which uses **Test API Key** . Is there a way to "recreate" or generate new `stripe_customer_ids` in staging keeping the rest of user data in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Stripe's dev team, loading live data in test env and vice-versa is currently impossible although they are considering implementing it in the future.

Our order data was stored locally, so we ended up running a rake task, recreating live users in staging and assigning new stripe id to each record. Note that keeping the same email for each customer will raise exceptions because emails were already registered in production under valid stripe_ids, so you may want to include some sort of a prefix to each row.

Comment: would love this functionality in our staging environment. we had to push a hotfix because it's difficult to determine what is a bug on staging versus just a fake data issue